# Can I create a transparent GIF with After Effects?

Tags: transparency, resize, gif, adobe-after-effects, video

I'm trying to create a transparent GIF using After Effects but I can't get it just right. I make a transparent video but when I use the GIF makers they resize it. I even now have a PNG sequence.

Is there anyway I can make the GIF without changing the size?

I only have Photoshop and After Effects.

Comment: Do you have two problems? Video to gif converters you are using resize it.... And turn the background opaque? Or maybe just one of those. Photoshop has a 500 frame limit, but otherwise it does the job. It's kinda hard to say what is going on. I guess, make sure you don't have a background layer in photoshop. Unless you ran the resize command and are now wondering why it's smaller... The likelier mistake may be the output from after effects. Maybe the output size is smaller than the original. What if you check your png sequence to see if they are smaller before you import to PS.

Comment: I tend to output a lossless  .mov from AE. it's a bit nicer to manage.

Comment: Oh... you didn't say that you tried to use Photoshop for making the gif. You should try it. I believe Gif Export disappeared after like After Effects CS 4 or something, due to licensing issues or something... something. So you can't natively export gif straight from AE. There is a paid extension for it though: [GifGun](http://aescripts.com/gifgun/). The simplest method (on mac)  would be to export that lossless .mov with video output channel: `RGB + Alpha`, so the output has that transparent bg... and then use [Gifrocket](http://www.gifrocket.com/) to convert it to gif.

Answer (score 6):

After Effects hasn't been able to directly export GIFs for some time now. There are plugins available that'll do it or you should be able to use the Media Encoder if you're on Windows (I don't use Windows so I'm just going on what the documentation says).

See [How to export a GIF from After Effects?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91994/52050)

Otherwise you'll have to export something that supports transparency from After Effects then import in to Photoshop and export as a GIF from there. I usually export a PNG sequence but you could export a lossless MOV too. Most of the following applies regardless of the output format..

From the render queue, choose the format from the Output Module Settings dialog and make sure the video output channels are set to "RGB + Alpha" (otherwise it will output without the transparency). Also make sure "Resize" isn't checked.

[image]

From the Render Settings dialog, make sure the resolution is set to "Full" (and the corresponding "size" is correct). You can change your frame rate here too (you generally don't want a GIF at ~30 fps or whatever your video is).

[image]

After outputting your PNG sequence, open them in Photoshop by selecting the first in the sequence in the file open dialog (clicking "Options" if needs be) and making sure "Image Sequence" is checked. Set the frame rate in the dialog that pops up next to the same as you set in the output from After Effects.

[image]

Use Photoshop's "Save For Web" to export the GIF. Make sure "Transparency" is checked (you'll see the transparency grid in the preview) and make sure your image size is set to 100%.

[image]

You should now have a transparent GIF at the correct size.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/43af59eb321852f33496f143d4f1fe79

i try it but this is what comes out and I even try it with a different metod with my mac and I still get the same error

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You must export all frames to .png and then make animated in program whose support transperent gifs like Photoshop.

PS Here is tutorial how to make GIFs in Photoshop https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-create-animated-gif-quick-tip-ht

Comment: I try this but I got this error https://gyazo.com/43af59eb321852f33496f143d4f1fe79

Comment: Download last version of Photoshop. I advise you to download Photoshop from creative cloud. You have 14 days free trail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is currently (CC 2018) an issue with this workflow. Importing as an image sequence imports as a video. But you'll have better luck as frame per layer, which is how gifs are opened. That way you can do things like get rid of duplicate frames and change how long that frame holds.

So if you want to do that, until Adobe makes a better workflow, export as a MOV with RGB+A. Import that into photoshop using import (not place or open) and then you can make those edits before doing save for web. PNG sequence should be able to do that, but it doesn't seem that you can.

This will keep your hard drive more cleaned up anyway because you'll have fewer files to keep track of.

Hopefully, they'll just add some gif image controls in AME some time. For now, the only way to export an animated gif is to use a tool they are calling legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. We've developed a free script for After Effects that exports GIFs in 1 click. It's called AEJuice GIF. You can download it and learn more at [this blog post](https://aejuice.com/blog/how-to-make-a-gif-in-after-effects/).

After installation, go to Window - AEJuice GIF (on the bottom).
Open a composition, press Render in the script.
It will export a GIF animation and open it after a render.
There are plenty of settings including transparent backgrounds.